# Dynamically access property using variable

Tags: vala

How does one retrieve a property from an object when the name of that property name is a variable?

Simply using the following doesn't seem to work

```
object[prop_name]
```

In this case it's to dynamically retrieve a value from a `GLib.Object` after it changed:

```
device.notify[prop_name].connect((s, p) => {
   debug ("  updated: %s", device[prop_name]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work

```
string value;
device.get (prop_name, out value);
debug ("  update: %s", value);
```

Comment: Correct, you can even get multiple property values at once: https://valadoc.org/gobject-2.0/GLib.Object.@get.html

Comment: Setting works with `set`, change notify with the `notify` signal and there is even cooler stuff like binding to properties together in `GLib.Object`. It goes without saying this only works for classes derived from `GLib.Object`.